# Alternative to pessimistic locking to objects that are constantly/concurrently updated

Tags: design-patterns, database-design, software-design, pessimistic-locking

Currently we are developing a credit transaction system on Grails 2.4.4.

We have a Credit model that holds the amount of credits of a User.

```
class Credit {
    BigDecimal amount
    User user
}
```

Problem is the amount is constantly debited/credited as the users transact.

We tried to do pessimistic locking on it to maintain integrity of it. But we realized that it bottle necks transactions since that user can only transact one at a time.

Any alternative to this? Any design patterns we can use?
We are open to altering the model, or taking other approaches.

Comment: Take a look at Event Sourcing pattern. It solves many concurrent transactions problem. The best article I could find for your case is http://coding-time.blogspot.ru/2013/06/transactions-in-real-world.html Event sourcing section.

Comment: Postponing the highly contended row updates to the very end of the transaction does not help either?

Comment: @FireAlkazar We record debits/credits to the Credit model as Transactions, so we can already reverse it later on if necessary. But still, we have to lock the Credit objects to ensure integrity.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic That's a good work around, but it will still be a bottle neck since we expect certain Credit entries are going to be the receiving end of almost all of the transactions.

Comment: @froi As I can see reversing is one of the the properties, another one a is lock free model. Like a queue, nothing stops you to insert an item, while in parallel you deque and handle a request. You can have different strategies to deque and  garantee integrity.

Comment: @FireAlkazar Hm, if I understand correctly, that would mean I will need to have a single event processor that will listen to a queue. In that case, you are right, I don't need to lock. But in that case, the events will be processed on a single thread and I need to have the processing concurrent/ multithreaded.
Please point me to the right direction if I misunderstood.

Comment: @froi We can imagine that we have different queues for different users. If so, you can handle different users in parallel, having one processor for queue. Another option would be to deque in such a way, that the operation amount becomes frozen so you can handle other operations in parallel and always, for example, have balance >= 0.

Comment: @FireAlkazar I believe your solution can work. I'll give it a try. I you post it as an answer, I'd gladly consider it.

Comment: You could split the critical amounts to multiple rows and update them separately.

Comment: @DraganBozanovic Do you mean multiple rows in the database? Can you expound more on it?

Comment: Yes, for example, split the `amount` of 10,000$ to 10 rows containing 1000$. Then pick a random row (or by using round-robin or something else depending of your server architecture) to update when debit/credit. Of course, there will be maintenance overhead (when a row is getting close to 0 or when a withdrawal larger than 1000$ happens, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Event Sourcing pattern.
There is a lot to learn about, but one of the properties it provides is a lock free model.
If you will be interested, find Greg Young and Udi Dahan videos. They talk and teach a lot about the topic.

Comment: Can you provide a link on the video that they talked about that pattern? I mostly find cqrs related stuff.